Class heap allocation
I am running some allocation tests and getting confused by allocation results.
Assume this is a test where a class is created multiple times, its reference never escapes the method.
 [Benchmark]
 public void AllocateClass()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
     {
         var s = new SampleClass();             
     }           
 }

When the tests finishes the total allocated memory is zero.
Now with second test where reference escapes the method.
SampleClass s;
[Benchmark]
public void AllocateClass()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        s = new SampleClass();                
    }           
}

With the second test memory is allocated as expected.
Since class is reference type I would expect it to be allocated on heap no matter if its reference escapes or not, is this some compiler optimization ?

your first snippet basically does nothing. I assume the JIT compiler simply skips the whole allocation.

^^ That's what I'd assume, too. But I guess, this isn't your actual benchmark, is it?

Maybe you'll want to return a collection and avoid deferred execution: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/samples/IntroDeferredExecution.html#sample-introdeferredexecution to get correct benchmarks ...

Bear in mind that an object can be collected even when its own constructor is still running. Providing it can be proven that nothing attempts to dereference it later.

Rather than using a Benchmark (and undisclosed project build and runtime settings...) you should use the GC Performance Counters to get the actual data.

@Fildor Not sure what you mean by actual benchmark, I am just trying to get a better understanding of allocations. What I can see is that once any of the created class properties gets an value assigned then the actual allocation happens.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever "Bear in mind that an object can be collected even when its own constructor is still running." - Please elaborate...

"Not sure what you mean by actual benchmark" - I was wondering if that's only a simplifacation of a different benchmark that yielded unexpected figures as this doesn't make much sense, as it is. Creating an object and immediatly letting it run out of scope - I'd expect all sorts of compiler/JIT magic to happen, which will be hard to track down. If you need it to not be collected until your measurement is done, hold on to a (hard) reference.

Compare. The JIT indeed completely removed the construction of a trivial class

@canton7 Thanks, so indeed this is due compiler optimization.

@NullReference A runtime opimisation: the compiler doesn't do things like this. Switch the drop-down at the top to "IL" to see what the compiler output

Also classes don't have to be allocated on the heap. That's traditionally how it's been done, but it's not a guarantee. The runtime is starting to experiment with limited forms of escape analysis, which can allocate a class on the stack in certain situations, if it can be proved that a reference to it never escapes the current method

@Dai A class can be freed/finalized once it reaches the point that it's never used again, regardless of whether any references to it are still in scope (scope is irrelevant), including when one of its own methods is executing. This includes construction. See here. This of course comes with a bunch of complications around unmanaged resources being released while still in use / when not yet initialised, which is why we recommend people avoid finalizers and use SafeHandles.

@Dai Looks like BenchmarkDotNet is being used, which is very well regarded for benchmarking and heap analysis. As to being freed while a constructor is running: in Release mode the GC can decide there is no further use for the this reference (which is actually just a hidden argument) and the outer function also doesn't hold any reference (as the variable has been optimized away) so the object can be freed,

I guess you run your Benchmark in Release mode and your observed behavior is most likely a compiler optimization.
You can use https://sharplab.io to do some experiments and look at the generated IL and asm.
For example some JIT Asm from SharpLab in Release mode:
Method with eliminated allocation:
C.AllocateClass(Int32)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: xor eax, eax
    L0005: test edx, edx
    L0007: jle short L000e
    L0009: inc eax
    L000a: cmp eax, edx
    L000c: jl short L0009
    L000e: pop ebp
    L000f: ret

Method without eliminated code:
C.AllocateClass(Int32)
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: sub esp, 0x18
    L0006: xor eax, eax
    L0008: mov [ebp-0xc], eax
    L000b: mov [ebp-0x10], eax
    L000e: mov [ebp-0x14], eax
    L0011: mov [ebp-0x18], eax
    L0014: mov [ebp-4], ecx
    L0017: mov [ebp-8], edx
    L001a: cmp dword ptr [0x2bb6c18c], 0
    L0021: je short L0028
    L0023: call 0x71f90f30
    L0028: nop
    L0029: xor ecx, ecx
    L002b: mov [ebp-0xc], ecx
    L002e: nop
    L002f: jmp short L0067
    L0031: nop
    L0032: mov ecx, 0x2bb6ca04
    L0037: call 0x0704300c
    L003c: mov [ebp-0x14], eax
    L003f: mov ecx, [ebp-4]
    L0042: mov ecx, [ecx+4]
    L0045: mov [ebp-0x18], ecx
    L0048: mov ecx, [ebp-0x14]
    L004b: call dword ptr [0x2bb6ca24]
    L0051: push dword ptr [ebp-0x14]
    L0054: mov ecx, [ebp-0x18]
    L0057: mov edx, [ebp-0xc]
    L005a: call System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.StelemRef(System.Array, IntPtr, System.Object)
    L005f: nop
    L0060: mov eax, [ebp-0xc]
    L0063: inc eax
    L0064: mov [ebp-0xc], eax
    L0067: mov ecx, [ebp-0xc]
    L006a: cmp ecx, [ebp-8]
    L006d: setl cl
    L0070: movzx ecx, cl
    L0073: mov [ebp-0x10], ecx
    L0076: cmp dword ptr [ebp-0x10], 0
    L007a: jne short L0031
    L007c: nop
    L007d: mov esp, ebp
    L007f: pop ebp
    L0080: ret


"I guess you run your Benchmark in Release mode" - BenchmarkDotnet will bail out with an error message if you are not running in Release Mode.
